# Swipe from the edge of screen, over UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, swipe

[image: Scheme of views]

**Greetings to everyone!**

I have :

- A view - is main view of UIViewController
- B view - is UIView and subview of A view (A_view.addsubview(B_view))
- C view - is UICollectionView and subview of A view ...

**What is problem?**

I can`t catch touch, swipe events in parent view controller.

**What do I mean?**

When I try to catch touch event using :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {...
```

in A View controller I can see such results.

**I try to catch swipes by UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer added to A_view**

Touch on A View -> touchesBegan(...) -> works

Swipe on A View -> UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer -> works

Touch on B View -> touchesBegan(...) -> works

Swipe on B View -> UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer -> works

Touch on C View -> touchesBegan(...) -> doesn't work

Swipe on C View -> UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer -> doesn't work

I noticed that I can catch touch events in C view controller.

**Question**

Is there possibility to catch swipe/touch events produced on C view ( UICollectionView) in A view controller (UIViewController).

**My Goal**

My goal is to make SideBar view, and when I try to catch swipe on the edge of screen over C view (UICollectionView) it just scrolling inside, but I want to open SideBar when finger start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the function: `optional func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool` in the parent `A View` & return appropriate BOOLs. 
Keep in mind that for a view whose `userInteractionEnabled` attribute is set to `true`, any touches/gestures in that view won't be propagated to the parent view (*unless `shouldReceive touch` is overrided to say otherwise*)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the edge swipe gesture to be recognized over every scrollView. (UICollectionView is a UIScrollView)

```
extension UIScrollView {
    open override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        print("gesture recognizer should begin")
        print(gestureRecognizer)
        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        if let view = app?.window?.rootViewController?.view, !(gestureRecognizer is UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
            let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
            if location.x < view.frame.maxX * 0.05 || location.x > view.frame.maxX * 0.95 {
                return false
            }
        }
        return super.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I have added `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to parent classes of `A View` viewController.

   ```
   class A_viewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{...
   ```
2. I have added `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to `A view` - parent view.

   ```
   let rec = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestRecognizer))
   rec.edges = .left
   rec.delegate = self
   A_view.addGestureRecognizer(rec)
   ```
3. Using method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(...)` catch edge swipes, and calling `handlePanGestRecognizer(...)` method to produce action. If `gestureRecognizer` is `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` than do action.

   ```
   func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
   {
        if gestureRecognizer is UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer
        {
            handlePanGestRecognizer(recognizer: gestureRecognizer as! UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
        }
        return false
   }
   ```
4. Beside that `recognizer.state.rawvalue` = 0, so `recognizer.state` is not `.begun` when `handlePanGestRecognizer()` method fired.

   ```
   func handlePanGestRecognizer(recognizer : UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer){...
   ```